# How to write special characters like new line, and format output of haddock

Tags: haskell, haddock

I would like to format my haddock documentation as I do with javadoc, something like inserting html or any other markup that let me get a cleaner output without uncluding any javascript or CSS... Specially, I would like to know how to insert a line break in the documentation.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haddock is designed to work with multiple output formats, including LaTeX, so it uses [its own markup format](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html) instead of something like HTML.

I don't think you can insert just a line break, but you can start a new paragraph by leaving a blank line, e.g.

```
-- | First paragraph.
--
-- Second paragraph.
```