# How do I incorporate a blank line into a Haddock example?

Tags: haskell, haddock

Haddock supports [blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424442/656912), and supports [REPL examples](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idm140354810775744). But I can't figure out how to show a blank line in an example.

For example, if 'f' prints out two lines separated by a blank line

```
ghci> f
Line1

Line 2
```

The corresponding Haddock example

```
-- >>> f
-- Line1
-- 
-- Line 2
```

only generates

> ```
> >>> f
> Line1
> ```
>
> Line2

In other words, it ends the example at the first blank line and treats what follows as a regular comment.

Is there a way to show blank likes in Haddock REPL examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply using

```
<BLANKLINE>
```

[should work](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idm140354810775744).